# Creating a singleton DB helper class

Tags: ios, sqlite, helper

I am trying to write a Master-Detail application that gets it's data from a sqlite database. As part of this I'm trying to create a helper class that creates a singleton instance of my database. All I want it to do is initialise the database so I can then reference this from the different views of the application. 
I followed a tutorial that does this here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app

I got the tutorial to work however now I am trying to modify it to fit my application and I can't seem to get it working. I have no errors or warnings but when I run the app on the emulator none of the debug text I have put in executes. So it looks to me like my init function is not executing. I just can't figure out why.
Can anyone spot my problem in the code below?

LoyaltyProgramDatabase.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface LoyaltyProgramDatabase : NSObject {
    sqlite3 *_loyaltyProgDB;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath; //Path file of our database
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *loyaltyProgDB; //Reference to the database

+ (LoyaltyProgramDatabase*)loyaltyProgDB;

@end
```

LoyaltyProgramDatabase.m

```
#import "LoyaltyProgramDatabase.h"

@implementation LoyaltyProgramDatabase

static LoyaltyProgramDatabase *_loyaltyProgDB;

//Create a singleton instance of loyaltyProgDB
+ (LoyaltyProgramDatabase*)loyaltyProgDB {
    if (_loyaltyProgDB == nil) {
        _loyaltyProgDB = [[LoyaltyProgramDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return _loyaltyProgDB;
}

- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"Inside init function");
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

        // Get the documents directory
        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"loyaltyProg.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_loyaltyProgDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scoreCard (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, campaignID INTEGER, merchantName TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_loyaltyProgDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //_status.text = @"Failed to create table";
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }
            sqlite3_close(_loyaltyProgDB);
        } else {
            //_status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }        
}    
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    sqlite3_close(_loyaltyProgDB);
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you ever call `[LoyaltyProgramDatabase loyaltyProgDB]`?

Comment: Also, that tutorial is from about 3 years ago... very out of date. RayWenderlich should have much better tutorials.

Comment: @ColdLogic No, I never call `[LoyaltyProgramDatabase loyaltyProgDB]` as my understanding was that there was no need because the database is initiated in the `-(id)init` function automatically when the app starts.

Comment: Oh how I wish `init` functions were called automatically. But unfortunately, that is not the case. You can tell your init isn't being called since none of your NSLogs are being displayed. Check the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   + (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self loyaltyProgDB];
}

+ (LoyaltyProgramDatabase*)loyaltyProgDB
{
    static BNRImageStore *loyaltyProgDB = nil;
    if (!loyaltyProgDB) {
        // Create the singleton
        loyaltyProgDB = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return loyaltyProgDB;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

        // Get the documents directory
        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        docsDir = dirPaths[0];

        // Build the path to the database file
        _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"loyaltyProg.db"]];

        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
        {
            const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_loyaltyProgDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                char *errMsg;
                const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scoreCard (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, campaignID INTEGER, merchantName TEXT)";

                if (sqlite3_exec(_loyaltyProgDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    //_status.text = @"Failed to create table";
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
                }
                sqlite3_close(_loyaltyProgDB);
            } else {
                //_status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
                NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't give me any error's or warnings but my NSLog's still aren't showing up.

Comment: You must call loyaltyProgDB to create and init the singleton instance.
I.e. 
LoyaltyProgramDatabase *loyaltyProgDBSingleToneInstance = [LoyaltyProgramDatabase loyaltyProgDB];

Answer (score 0):

If you have not written a line of code that says `[[LoyaltyProgramDatabase alloc] init]` or `[LoyaltyProgramDatabase loyaltyProgDB]`, then your `init` function is never getting called.

The `init` is not automatically called when you start the app. The only time any `init` function is called automatically is if you have a UI element in a nib/xib/storyboard file, and the app creates the element utilizing various initialization functions, but never your own `init` function. But for something like what you have written, to initialize the database object, you need to call the `init` function yourself.

In your app delegate, under the `didFinishLaunching` function, put this line:

```
[LoyaltyProgramDatabase loyaltyProgDB];
```

This isn't a really up-to-date singleton pattern by the way. This is actually a lazy loader function. If you want a more secure singleton, use this code.

```
+(id)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
  __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return _sharedObject;
}
```

This will make sure the database is only ever initialized once and it is thread safe. To create/use the singleton, the code would change from the above to

```
[LoyaltyProgramDatabase sharedInstance]
```